# Optimization: memcached vs mysql memory

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I am developing highload application, and thinking whether to use memcache or mysql memory table. Table is tiny, not more than 30-40 rows and in most cases the application reads them all at once. (like select * from table and fetches all rows) May be someone has information about how much better is memcache in such situation?

Comment: Why not just write an array that is included? No need for memcache, no need to make a mysql connection - no need for anything really - the performance is the best you will get. Unless the data changes often, it won't be an issue at all.

Comment: Sure, most of the data, which can be altered only by me I store in config files. I speak about data, which is changed by users.

Comment: Have you determined that fetching an entire 40-row table is the slowest part of the app?  We are talking milliseconds.

Comment: Not of the whole app, but in general mysql queries consume most time. It is web-based and multiuser, so even one millisecond multiplied by thousand users is not so few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, memcached is better and faster! **BUT:** memcached can remove old keys, if ttl expires or small size for sets other keys.

The situation may be:

1. In first request you set key-value to memcached.
2. In second request (parallel) you set another key value to memcached, and in memcached small memory for save this keys, and memcacehd remove older keys (sets in first request).

When compared **Memcached** and **MySQL**, i would choose MySQL, because data not will be deleted in any situation.

P.S. **Redis** - it is best to be approached.

Comment: In fact I am not using memcache but files in ram (I checked, they work a bit faster, and also it's easy to view the data using ftp client, just wrote memcache as it is widely known), so data will not expire.